# is there a workaround around broken Visual Studio map of unique_ptr?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11, unique-ptr

Visual studio 2012 has a bug that makes map unusable with unique_ptr:

> error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access
>   private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'   c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\utility   203

g++ compiles this nicely:

```
 std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<int> > banarama;
```

Is there a workaround around this? Except storing raw ptrs and deleete-ing them IDK what I could do....

Comment: I suspect `shared_ptr` would work correctly, if somewhat more slowly. +1 for Bananarama in any case.

Comment: I know about sp, code im fixing is acually using shared_ptr, and I find it ugly and deceitful and slow :)

Comment: That compiles nicely in VS2012 update 3 as well.  Keep yours updated or give a better example.

Comment: unique_ptr still give me "deleted function copy constructor" when I try to use it in STL containers. this VS bug is really weird. Isn't there any workaround ( I can't drop unique_ptr, since they are the only pointer that guarantee there are no circular references)? (Bug still present in VS 2013 TP 2)